# Using flash text in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use [flash text](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) in django. I think that `KeyWordProcessor` should be called only once. So i have defined it in settings.py file as this:

**settings.py**

```
KEYWORD_PROCESSOR = None
```

Then i am calling function `KeywordProcessor()` on app start like this:

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MywebappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mywebapp'

    def ready(self):
        import mywebapp.signals
        from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
        from django.conf import settings
        from mywebapp.utils import add_all_kewords_to_flash_text
        import threading

        settings.KEYWORD_PROCESSOR = KeywordProcessor()
        add_all_kewords_to_flash_text()

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=add_all_kewords_to_flash_text)
        t1.start()
```

**utils.py**

```
def add_keyword_to_flash_text(keyword_obj):

    if not settings.KEYWORD_PROCESSOR:
        raise ValueError("Flash text is None")

    added = settings.KEYWORD_PROCESSOR.add_keywords_from_dict(
        {keyword_obj.keyword: [keyword_obj.keyword]+keyword_obj.tags}
        )    


def add_all_kewords_to_flash_text():
    add_all_kewords = [add_keyword_to_flash_text(k) for k in KeyWord.objects.all()]
```

But i am getting this error: **ValueError: Flash text is None**

Answer (score 2):

The settings file is there to define constants and you shouldn't be attempting to mutate constants (I.E it's immutable).

You can't change the settings after they have been loaded. So trying to do

```
settings.KEYWORD_PROCESSOR = KeywordProcessor()
```

Isn't going to work.

Take a closer look at [the documentation](https://flashtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

You're probably better writing a class to handle this, and initiating the class in the app config ready method.

```
class MyKeywordProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
```

Then in app config

```
class MywebappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mywebapp'

    def ready(self):
        ...

        keyword_processor = MyKeywordProcessor()
        add_all_kewords_to_flash_text(keyword_processor)
        ...
```

As you can see I've passed the keyword processor to your `add_all_kewords_to_flash_text` function which is the instance of the KeywordProcessor object.

Comment: I am adding and removing keywords from KeywordProcessor on ```post_save``` and ```post_delete``` signals as well. My understanding is calling ```KewordProcessor()``` makes a structure for us and we add/remove keywords from it. If i will keep on calling ```KeywordProcessor()``` every time then it will generate a new structure and my previously added keywords will be gone.  It should be like structure should be made once when app starts, add all the keywords from database to structure, then keep on listening signals whenever any new keyword is added/removed. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't know much about this library but my point is, you can't reassign the value of settings.KEYWORD_PROCESSOR. I've updated my answer with a potentially better solution

Comment: shouldn't it be ```keyword_processor = MyKeywordProcessor()``` in ready() function. Thanks for helping me , i will accept it once implemented at my end.

Comment: That is correct, sorry it's been a long day.